# Magento error when adding coupon code

Tags: php, magento

I created a new coupon code, and it worked great the day before.  Today, I get this error:
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

And this is the code I get when viewing the error:

> a:5:{i:0;s:138:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in app/code/community/Gala/Bigshopsettings/Helper/Data.php, line 1";i:1;s:1718:"#0 >lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
>
> ## 1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php(107): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('http://www.capi...', 302)
>
> ## 2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(711): Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http->setRedirect('http://www.capi...')
>
> ## 3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(689): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->setRedirectWithCookieCheck('checkout/cart', Array)
>
> ## 4 app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_redirect('checkout/cart')
>
> ## 5 app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(595): Mage_Checkout_CartController->_goBack()
>
> ## 6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->couponPostAction()
>
> ## 7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('couponPost')
>
> ## 8 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> ## 9 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> ## 10 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> ## 11 index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> ## 12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:26:"/checkout/cart/couponPost/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}

Any suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in app/code/community/Gala/Bigshopsettings/Helper/Data.php

As it says line 1 you need to check some white spaces or special characters before php starat tag.

Comment: Thanks!  I can't seem to vote you up, but that was the issue.

Comment: Nice to know it sorted out.I think you need some points before you can vote.